Why does EmbeddedId mapping fail to load data correctly after upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.3 or later?
We are experiencing issues after upgrading the Spring Boot version to 3.2.3 or later.
We have an N x N mapping between Student and Course. We use EmbeddedId to handle the mapping.
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT", schema = "COLLEGE_OWNER")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_STUDENT_OID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_STUDENT_OID", sequenceName = "SEQ_STUDENT_OID", allocationSize = 1, schema = "COLLEGE_OWNER")
    @Column(name = "OID_STUDENT")
    private Long oidStudent;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "student")
    private Set<StudentCourse> studentCourseList;

    
    @NotBlank(message = "The nomeSolicitante field cannot be blank or null.")
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String studentName;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSE", schema = "SPIAPIPIX_OWNER")
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_COURSE_OID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_COURSE_OID", sequenceName = "SEQ_COURSE_OID", allocationSize = 1, schema = "COLLEGE_OWNER")
    @Column(name = "OID_COURSE")
    private Long oidCourse;

    @Size(max = 100, message = "The courseName field must contain a maximum of 100 characters")
    @Column(name = "COURSE_NAME", length = 100)
    private String courseName;
}

The StudentCourse entity using @EmbeddedId
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Validated
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT_COURSE", schema = "COLLEGE_OWNER")
public class StudentCourse {
    @EmbeddedId
    @Valid
    @NotNull(message = "The fiield studentCourseId can't be null")
    @Builder.Default
    private StudentCourseId studentCourseId = new StudentCourseId();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("oidStudent")
    @JoinColumn(name = "OID_STUDENT")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("oidCourse")
    @JoinColumn(name = "OID_COURSE")
    private Course course;
}

The entity responsible for the oid mapping
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class StudentCourseId implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Column(name = "OID_STUDENT")
    private Long oidStudent;

    @NotNull(message = "The oidCourse field cannot be null")
    @Column(name = "OID_COURSE")
    private Long oidCourse;
}

The problem occurs when performing any operation that retrieves information from the database for the Embeddable class StudentCourseId. The information is not loaded, and the object has the fields oidStudent and oidCourse set to null. In version 3.2.2 and earlier, we did not have this problem.
We have identified that the issue occurs starting from version 3.2.3. We have already tested it with the latest version 3.3.X
